# Read cosmosDb documents in nodejs bot

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I set up my v4 bot built using botbuilder v4 SDK to use cosmosDb storage. 
Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#using-cosmos-db) which explains the concept.

here is the example document from cosmosDb that my BOT has created.

```
{
    "id": "emulator*2fconversations*2f58ceae60-ac37-ef89ad70c779|livechat*2f",
    "realId": "emulator/conversations/58ceae60-ac37-ef89ad70c779|livechat/",
    "document": {
        "dialogStateKey": {
            "dialogStack": [
                {
                    "id": "who_are_you",
                    "state": {
                        "options": {},
                        "values": {
                            "instanceId": "d73-cc97-85fb-669e490c54fa"
                        },
                        "stepIndex": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "name_prompt",
                    "state": {
                        "options": {
                            "prompt": "What is your name, human?"
                        },
                        "state": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_rid": "CAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "",
    "_etag": "",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1549230
}
```

I would like to read above document back in the code so that I can look at dialogStack [] to see if stack is empty.

**Is there any API or NPM package that I can use to interact with cosmosDb?**

Note: All the write operations to cosmosDB are managed by botframework.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking; there's an entire SDK for working with Cosmos DB, for several languages (including node.js). I'd start with that. As written though, your question isn't really specific on what you're trying to do. Please edit your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, expected vs actual results of queries, etc.

Comment: As @David Makogon stated, your question isn't very specific, but it sounds like you're looking for a node module to interact with CosmoDb. I would recommend looking at the [Azure Cosmos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos) npm package.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing provided by the Bot Builder SDK to perform ad-hoc queries over the bot state. That said, you can of course use [the standalone Cosmos DB npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos) to query over the stored state documents.

I would only caution that the structure of the stored state documents is sort of an internal implementation detail and subject to change later. I would also recommend you store longer term business domain specific data outside of bot state for this reason.